# How to handle HID device with CreateFile()?

Tags: c#, hid, createfile

I'm trying to connect to barcode scanner (is a HID device). I was able to receive data using RawInput, but I want to try using CreateFile().

```
deviceInformation.ReadHandle = Kernel32.CreateFile(
                    deviceInformation.DevicePathName,
                    Constants.GenericRead,
                    Constants.FileShareRead | Constants.FileShareWrite,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Constants.OpenExisting,
                    Constants.FileFlagOverlapped,
                    0);
int it = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

CreateFile() returns this:

[image: CreateFile's return object]

Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns 5 which is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

I'm using [this source code](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/530836/Csharp-USB-HID-Interface?fid=1824908&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=51#xx0xx) as the reference.

My questions are: Is it possible to create a handle to that hid device using CreateFile()? If yes, why do I receive Access denied? and what is the correct way to create a handle?

PS: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Are you using the Windows "Bomb-packed" (Compact) Framework?

Comment: Have you tried running with administrative privileges?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, I'm not sure if it is Compact Framework. Don't know how to check it. But it is said .Net Framework 2.0 in Project's Properties

Comment: @RonBeyer, yes, I've tried. Result's the same